# Parse HTML div id include all inner contents

Tags: php, parsing, dom, xpath

I am attempting to parse a html file and retreive all the contents within the div

```
$some_html = file_get_contents($html);   
$dom = new DOMDocument();   
@$dom->loadHtml($some_html);//Strict error checking off     

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);      
$result = $xpath->query('//*[@id="IDX-detailsWrapper"]');    
 if (!empty($result)) {    
    foreach ( $result as $link ) {var_dump($link->nodeValue); }}
```

The html:

```
<div id="IDX-detailsWrapper"><div id=content><h1>test</h1></div></div>
```

I'm hoping to retrieve the following string

```
  `<div id=content><h1>test</h1></div>`
```

instead of

```
  `test`
```

Currently its only retrieving the text contained within the div and not the html.

Though im not sure of an exact practice of doing such!

Thanks JT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i ended up using a library from http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/

and the sample code that works is

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');         
$html = file_get_html($html);
foreach($html->find('div#IDX-detailsWrapper') as $e)
echo $e->innertext . '<br>';
```

Hope this helps someone :)